# How to set fixed number of ticks despite the number of date range

Tags: d3.js

I have about 10 charts with different number of dates on x axis. From couple of weeks to months.
I want to display only 5 dates on x axis equally all the dates range. How to do this? Here is the code

```
 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(5)
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y"))
```

This does not works. It sets about 10 ticks instead of 5.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use below across all your charts:

```
var someConstant = 5;
yourAxis.ticks(someCostant);
```

Comment: This don't guarantee a constant number of ticks.

Comment: Yes I just discovered that now while creating a fiddle, but may tickValues can solve the problem if all 4 charts share a same range